# In Expo React Native, the image shows on development and also in .APK build but not on playstore version

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an expo app where I am fetching list of product and displaying it, the image works on development and even when I run .apk build it shows the image. But once I run the .aab build and push to playstore when I download the app the images fetched from the server do not show. I have been on this for the longest time, not quite sure what to look out for. Other items like product name, price and co shows correctly except the image.

Below is the code for rendering the image:

`<Image source={{ uri: item?.product_image?.imageUrl, }} style={styles.image} />`

```css
  image: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
```

When I use image on the local device, it shows but when I switch to getting from the server it does not work, even when I hardcoded the image uri, it still did not work. This is the image url to show the image exists: https://res.cloudinary.com/dkpeentvl/image/upload/v1691842935/Image/ut1kgltvufhnscg2ijnc.jpg

Comment: Where are you hosting the images?

Comment: I tried accessing the Link and the image works fine, without the actual code it might hard to debug the issue. But what you can do is maybe make sure the app has access network permission that allows it to access the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image url sent from the server was this http://res.cloudinary.com/dkpeentvl/image/upload/v1691842935/Image/ut1kgltvufhnscg2ijnc.jpg INSTEAD of this https://res.cloudinary.com/dkpeentvl/image/upload/v1691842935/Image/ut1kgltvufhnscg2ijnc.jpg

When I added "s" to the http, it started working.